# Class and method not see attribute asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner, why in my class and methods are not visible attributes (id, class button, table), what to add to the code?

```
    protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchWordDocument searchword = new SearchWordDocument();
        searchword.GetDocumentLibrary();
        //See atribute SearchField
    }
    public class SearchWordDocument {
        //Create array document
        //Not see atribute SearchField
        public void GetDocumentLibrary()
        {
         //Not see atribute SearchField          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SearchWordDocument` class has no relation to your ASP.NET page, so you'll have to pass it the relevant information.

Like so:

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchWordDocument searchword = new SearchWordDocument();

    var term = SearchField.Text;
    searchword.GetDocumentLibrary(term);
}

public class SearchWordDocument 
{   
    public void GetDocumentLibrary(string searchTerm)
    {
        // use searchTerm
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, if "SearchField" is a asp:Table?